# Banco de Dados em Linguagem C

Tags: c, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando solucionar esta questão:

[image: Banco de Dados]

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer a devida compilação. O meu código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
int idade;
char nome[50];
char sexo[2];
char estado_civil[2];
int qtd_amigos;
int qtd_fotos;
} cliente;

int main() {

int i, qtd;

scanf("%i", &qtd);

cliente clientes[qtd];  

for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {

    scanf(&clientes[i].idade);
    scanf(&clientes[i].nome,50, stdin);
    scanf(&clientes[i].sexo,2, stdin);
    scanf(&clientes[i].estado_civil, 2, stdin);
    scanf(&clientes[i].qtd_amigos);
    scanf(&clientes[i].qtd_fotos);
}

for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
    printf("Idade: %d\n", clientes[i].idade);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", clientes[i].nome);
    printf("Sexo: %s\n", clientes[i].sexo);
    printf("Estado Civil: %s\n", clientes[i].estado_civil);
    printf("Numero de amigos: %d\n", clientes[i].qtd_amigos);
    printf("Numero de fotos: %d\n", clientes[i].qtd_fotos);
}
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não há porque você declarar as variáveis sexo e estado_civil como char[2], declare-as apenas como char (afinal vão ocupar um único caractere e não existe a menor necessidade de ser um array). Seus scanf estão todos errados, você fez uma mistura das funções disponíveis em <stdio.h>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os seus scanf estavam todos mal feitos.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct{
    int idade;
    char nome[50];
    char sexo[2];
    char estado_civil[50];
    int qtd_amigos;
    int qtd_fotos;
    } cliente;

    int main() {

    int i, qtd;
    scanf("%d", &qtd);

    cliente clientes[qtd];  

    for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&clientes[i].idade);
        scanf("%s",&clientes[i].nome);
        scanf("%s",&clientes[i].sexo);
        scanf("%s",&clientes[i].estado_civil);
        scanf("%d",&clientes[i].qtd_amigos);
        scanf("%d",&clientes[i].qtd_fotos);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        printf("Idade: %d\n", clientes[i].idade);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", clientes[i].nome);
        printf("Sexo: %s\n", clientes[i].sexo);
        printf("Estado Civil: %s\n", clientes[i].estado_civil);
        printf("Numero de amigos: %d\n", clientes[i].qtd_amigos);
        printf("Numero de fotos: %d\n", clientes[i].qtd_fotos);
    }
        printf("\n");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Olá, agora há pouco tinha feito essas correções. Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: Note que na leitura de strings no scanf (%s) você não informa o endereço da variável ( este & inicial) pois já está fornecendo o endereço da posição inicial da string. Ou informe: scanf("%s",clientes[i].sexo); ou: scanf("%s",&clientes[i].sexo[0]);.

Comment: Sim, tem razão, erro meu. Antes tinha com %c, daí estar lá o "&", corrigi depois para %s e esqueci me de remover o &. Lapso meu